# "JOIN" is not valid at this position

Tags: mysql

I have a table name POEMS with columns poemID and users. I used this query with MYSQL Workbench:

```
SELECT poemID, COUNT(DISTINCT users) usersID 
FROM POEMS 
GROUP BY poemID;
```

And got this the table below.

```
|poemID | users |
   1       2
   2       3
   3       1
```

After I get back the query'd table I tried to immediately join to another table. but im getting the error: **"JOIN" is not valid at this position**. This is my sql code below.

```
SELECT poemID, COUNT(DISTINCT users) usersID
FROM POEMS 
GROUP BY poemID
JOIN users
ON users.id = poems.poemID;
```

Comment: the `GROUP BY` clause comes after `JOIN`

Comment: Even with the `JOIN` in its correct position, what's the point of joining the users on the users ID matching the poem ID? That doesn't seem useful at all... You probably should edit the question and add a proper [example] to get a really helpful answer.

Comment: @stickybit is correct, you probably want to join on `users.id = poems.usersID`

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` should come before the `GROUP BY`

Try:

```
SELECT poemID, COUNT(DISTINCT users) usersID
FROM POEMS
JOIN users ON users.id = poems.poemID
GROUP BY poemID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `JOIN` right after `FROM`, like this:

```
SELECT poemID, COUNT(DISTINCT users) usersID
FROM poems 
JOIN users ON users.id = poems.poemID
GROUP BY poemID;
```